# How to get user activity data using Google analytics 4 apis

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to get individual users activity using  google analytics apis for GA4. I am able to send UserID in GA data and also able to see these activities on analytics reports but unable to fetch this data using analytics apis.